# real time data acquisition/processing using Python

Tags: python, real-time-data

I am attempting to write a code that will acquire information from a buffer (returned as a multi-dimentional array), extract certain elements from said array.

So here's what I have:

```
Drest = np.array([])              #Set up array for data to be read to (not sure if this is needed)
t_end = time.time() + 5            
while time.time() < t_end:
Drest = ftc.getData()             #fts is the buffer that I'm connecting to.
print("Drest: %s" %Drest)
```

This returns an output which looks like this:

```
[[  6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01
6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01
6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01
6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01   6.79609478e-01]
[  6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01
6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01
6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01
6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01   6.81910694e-01]]
```

**Question 1** As the data comes in, I would like to add a "0" as a first element of each array, so I essentially have a first column full of zeros.  I have attempted this, but it doesn't add it to every one of, just the very first element, not the first in each element of each array.

```
block = 1
np.append(block, [Drest])
```

**Question 2**
I also need to create a mean of every other "column" from the multi-dimensional array, so I have tried this, but I can't for the life of me get this to work!

```
 for i in range(0, len(Drest), 2):
    HbO2 = Drest[i]
    HbO2Rest = sum(HbO2)/float(len(HbO2))
```

Thanks in anticipation of your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1:** As the data comes in, I would like to add a "0" as a first element of each array, so I essentially have a first column full of zeros. I have attempted this, but it doesn't add it to every one of, just the very first element, not the first in each element of each array.

```
import numpy as np
New_Drest = np.asarray([0 for x in xrange(len(Drest))])
Modified_Drest = np.concat(New_Drest,Drest)
```

**Question 2 :** I also need to create a mean of every other "column" from the multi-dimensional array, so I have tried this, but I can't for the life of me get this to work!

Numpy has a mean api.

```
 for i in xrange(len(Drest)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        HbO2 = Drest[i]
        HbO2Rest = np.mean(HbO2)
```

Python encourages to use xrange instead of range.

Comment: Yay :D thank you so much @Tammy (by the way, I came across an issue with xrange because I'm using python 3)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

Assuming that Drest an array or array:

```
b = [x.insert(0,0) for x in Drest]
```

**Question 2**

you can do about the same using slicing using the previously created array...

```
c = [sum(y[1:])/len(y[1:])*1.0 for y in b]
```

Comment: Hi there @pierre-Luc, thank you for your help... I don't know why but '"c = [sum(y[1:])/len(y[1:])*1.0 for y in b]"' isn't working... I'm not sure if it's because it's dealing a with a multidimentional array?  But the above solution worked quite nicely for my purposes.  Thanks again

Comment: @RichardSummers This would not work. If you look closely, it does not give you the mean of each 2nd column in the n-dimensional array. c = [sum(y[1:])/len(y[1:])*1.0 for y in b] will give you the mean of each row in the array. That is the reason why it failed to solve your problem

Comment: Step 1. Drest = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]  Step 2: [sum(y[1:]) for y in Drest] Step 3: [len(y[1:]) for y in Drest] Plus this is a n-dim array and not a numpy array